# How to enable join on columns with mismatched types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to enable joining two models, where one has an int id as it's primary key and the other has a varchar version of that value.

Using the standard ForeignKey attribute results in an error about mismatched types when creating the query.

How can I make this work. I want to be able to `.Include` the other model.

Comment: can you change database column type? XD

Comment: Why not convert type directly on Join? Can give the Join example you have?

Comment: @hamaronooo no.

Comment: @Miguel I don't have join. Yeah, I could write it that way and deal with setting the right fields myself, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. The question is how to make this situation work transparently and hydrate the right properties automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that you can assign a column TypeName completely different from the property type and the conversion will be either automatic, or can be defined through [value conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations).

In practice in my case it means I could use:

```
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Patient))]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
        public int PatientID { get; set; }
```

and any interaction with the column does the conversion transparently.

This works for the foreign key operations as well, so you can use `.Include` transparently as long as both sides agree on the type of the property.